# How do you say “To which the teacher would respond by saying “Fine. Give it to me tomorrow”.” in French (France)?

Tags: constructions

**SCENARIO**

---

**Person 1**: Have you completed your homework? The deadline is tomorrow.

**Person 2**: No. I have a plan.

**Person 1**: What are you going to do?

**Person 2**: I’m going to say “My laptop broke and it’s being repaired. It will be fixed by tomorrow.”. To which the teacher would respond by saying “Fine. Give it to me tomorrow.”.

---

I’m proposing « Par lequel le prof répondrait en disant “Très bien. Demandez-le à moi demain.” » Is this correct? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The following would be correct.

- Ce à quoi le  prof répondrait en disant “Très bien. Remettez-le  moi demain."

("demander" never means "donner" (to hand in something to someone).

Comment: Thank you for your help! 